# SiPM soldering with T962a oven not working (Pictures attached!)

Tags: pcb

For my new project, I was introduced to relatively new topic for me, Luminosity measurement with SiPM.

To do so, I am trying to make a SiPM PCB with SiPM soldered on it, which will be attached to measurement device.

In order to solder SiPM onto SiPM PCB (both pictures below), I was planning to use T962a reflow oven.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the past, I have successfully soldered LEDs on LED Boards using the reflow oven of T962a.

In addition, the manufacturer of SiPM also recommends standard reflow solder process (Link on Page 5: http://sensl.com/downloads/ds/TN-Handling%20and%20Soldering%20Guideline%20for%20%20SMT%20Devices.pdf)

So, I let the SiPM to be positioned on the PCB as in the picture and tried to solder in the T962a.

[image]

However, there was no soldering. It just came out as it was before soldering.

Could somebody teach me what is going on and instructions?

Thank you so much.

Comment: did you use flux and solder paste?

Comment: I used HARRIS Stay-clean paste soldering flux. So, it was PCB, with flux, and SiPM. It keeps slipping away...

Answer (score 1):

I can’t really tell from that photo, but assuming the solder paste didn’t melt and still looks “granular”, clean it off and replace it with fresh solder paste. Put it near the centre of the oven and slightly to the back, it works better if stood off with a couple bits of  scrap pcb material,

Try a hotter curve. This is a cheapie oven with not-so-great temperature control- the second run after it is hot will run hotter due to the lack of cold junction compensation. It can run acceptably well with SnPb solder using a hotter lead free curve. I suspect it will be more marginal with lead-free paste.

Consider improving the oven or budgeting for a better one (eg conveyorized),

Comment: Sir, I used Harris stay-clean soldering paste. The Solder paste definitely melt, actually it melted too much that I feel my PCB is inundated with cinnamon rosin or something.... It keeps slipping away.